# Unable to access pscp.exe with a windows service account

Tags: batch-file, cmd, service-accounts, pscp

I have built a windows batch file code that fetches the list of files from an FTP server and then pulls the appropriate file from that list. The batch file uses a combination of pscp.exe and psftp.exe in order to achieve this.

If I login as a member of the administrator group and execute this batch file manually (double clicking) it works perfectly, but the problem arises when I schedule a windows task to run that batch file from a windows service account (which is not in the administrator group).

The job when running under the windows service account is unable to execute the command for pscp.exe used in the code, whereas it executes everything else prior to that in the batch file perfectly normal.

Below is the line of code that I have used in my batch file :

`pscp.exe -sftp -v -batch -pw %password% -ls %username%@ServerAddress:/outbox > F:\dirlist.txt`

The service account is a member of BatchAccountsLG and ServiceAccountsLG groups, which is needed for the job to be able to execute the batch file code. Also, the service account has all the required access on any of the files/folders needed in the execution of the code.

I am not sure what the problem is because the batch file works perfectly fine if use my admin credentials, whereas it fails when the job is scheduled with the windows service account.

I have tried looking for an answer through google, but I have drawn a blank, any help on this would be highly appreciated. If there is anything else that I need to add to this, I would be more than glad to do so.

Thanks to all the ideas in advance.

Comment: Which windows service account? The LocalService account is a predefined local account. It has minimum privileges on the local computer and presents anonymous credentials on the network. The NetworkService account is a predefined local account.  It has minimum privileges on the local computer and acts as the computer on the network. The LocalSystem account is a predefined local account It has extensive privileges on the local computer, and acts as the computer on the network. Its token includes the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs.

Comment: @DavidCandy , it is a Network Service Account. I also noticed that the service account does not have privilege on cmd.exe
Though I strongly believe that the issue is just that the service account does not have 'enough' rights to execute the pscp.exe command successfully, but I am failing to understand what could be these rights.

Comment: Run you program normally in cmd. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 and r/c process - Properties - Security tab.